# How do I pass multiple query parameters to elastic search using the gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, elasticsearch, query-string

I need to append a string with special charters from a query to elasticsearch in rails. I try using `.html_safe`, and `raw()` it doesn't break anything, but it still passes the charters as hex or something.

these all pass the same thing to elasticsearch

```
<%= @esearch.search q:params[:query] + '&pretty=true' do %>

<%= @esearch.search q:params[:query] + '&pretty=true'.html_safe do %>

<%= @esearch.search q:params[:query] + raw('&pretty=true') do %>
```

I'm getting this:

```
q=asa%26pretty%3Dtrue
```

I'm hoping to get this:

```
q=asa&pretty=true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not running into an html-escaping issue.  `raw` and `html_safe` are only useful when you don't want output escape when *printed directly to a user's browser*.  For instance, the params would output `q=asa&amp;pretty=true` if you were running into an html-escaping problem, but you are not.

What you are seeing is the results of `CGI.escape` which outputs url-safe values.

It looks to me (based on your current use of the `search` method), that the hash options get translated to query params.  Have you tried this:

```
@esearch.search q: params[:query], pretty: true
```

I'm not sure what `search` is doing, but this seems like an odd method to be using directly in your view.  Of course I could be wrong on that since I don't know exactly what it's doing.

UPDATE:

Check out the documentation here: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/master/elasticsearch-api/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/search.rb#L15

There's two ways of sending query params, it looks like.  One is with that `q: 'title:text'` format which is what you're sending your `params[:query]` (but it looks like your query is just 'asa' so I'm not sure you're even using the right format there?) with, and the other is through the `body` hash:

```
@esearch.search body: {
  query: { match: { title: 'test' } },
  facets: { tags: { terms: { field: 'tags' } } }
}
```

You should look through that documentation including the links to the elastic search options documentation and figure out what you need to send it.  I don't see that `pretty: true` option in the docs so not sure what that's for.  But there's a lot of docs and I didn't really look at them extensively, I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: I think you nailed it. Witch only brings me to another question, how can I prevent it from happening? I did try pretty:true, and though it did not break anything, it did fix it either. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this the gem you're using?  https://github.com/karmi/retire  or is it something else?

Comment: I'm trying that one, and the new elasticsearch client. The new client is my preferred method, but I can not seem to get pretty to work, and there is not too much documentation yet. I think retire may work better for now, but I'm running into other issues with that one.

Comment: Can you link to what you're using then?

Comment: Here is the link to the new version. It does say that the integration into rails is not quite as good as tire, but is replacing tire. At least that's how I read it. https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-ruby

Comment: Hmm I've updated the answer with some links to the documentation that you might need to look at

Comment: I'm surprised to hear there's "not much documentation", have you seen http://rubydoc.info/gems/elasticsearch-api/ ?

Comment: The new Rails integration [https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails] is in fact superior to Tire in many aspects, and should be a drop-in replacement for Tire.